# How do I Install X13-arima-seats for Rstudio from source?

Tags: 12.04, install-from-source, statistical

Hello all and thanks for interest!

Im trying to install x13-arima-seats to be used with Rstudio. There are compiled version for RedHat and source available.

I have followed these steps from the official manual http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/seasonal/README.html. (links to all packages can be found from this manual because i couldn't add more than 2 links):

---

*To install the stable version directly from CRAN, type to the R console:*

```
install.packages("seasonal")
```

*seasonal does not includes the binary executables of X-13ARIMA-SEATS. They need to be installed separately from here (Windows, filename x13asall.zip) or here (Linux, filename x13asall.tar.gz). My own compilation for Mac OS-X can be obtained upon request. Download the file, unzip it and copy the folder to the desired location in your file system. Next, you need to tell seasonal where to find the binary executables of X-13ARIMA-SEATS, by setting the specific environmental variable X13 PATH. This may be done during your active session in R:*

```
Sys.setenv(X13_PATH = "YOUR_X13_DIRECTORY")
```

---

Anyway im stuck when i should compile extracted "x13asall.tar.gz".

```
root@t420s:/home/jori/Downloads/x13asall# make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
root@t420s:/home/jori/Downloads/x13asall# ./configure
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
root@t420s:/home/jori/Downloads/x13asall#
```

i used google and found this: http://iristoolbox.codeplex.com/discussions/528902#post1202601 which use "x13assrc.tar.gz" -package for building.

after modifying makefile.g77 as follow i get the same results

```
cd /path/to/x13assrc/folder
gedit makefile.g77

FC        = /usr/bin/gfortran # "which gfortran" gives this address
LINKER    = /usr/bin/gfortran

root@t420s:/home/jori/Downloads/x13assrc# make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
root@t420s:/home/jori/Downloads/x13assrc# ./configure
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
root@t420s:/home/jori/Downloads/x13assrc#
```

an additional info from my laptop

```
root@t420s:/home/jori/Downloads/x13assrc# gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04) 4.8.1

RStudio: Version 0.98.495
Ubuntu Release 12.04 (precise) 64-bit
Kernel Linux 3.8.0-26-generic
```

Maybe im missing some very basic things because i have always been able to install all the softwares from different repos. Please help, i need this package for one statistic course.

Comment: If the makefile is called `makefile.g77` instead of the normal `Makefile`, the error `No targets specified...` is because the makefile is not being detected. Try `make -f makefile.g77` to explicitly specify the makefile to use.

Comment: Thank you so much @chronitis ! You really made my day! Your answer solved my problem. I will add instructions if someone will have same issues. Thanks very much for a very quickly answer!

Answer (score 3):

OP posted: I will appreciate all responses!

### steps that worked for me:

Download source file (x13assrc.tar.gz) from webpage:

```
www.census.gov/ts/x13as/unix/x13assrc.tar.gz
```

extract it with right click or with dpkg

use sudo and go to to the extractred folder

```
sudo -i
cd /Downloads/x13assrc
```

change compiler from makefile.g77

```
gedit makefile.g77
```

change 2. and 3. rows to these. save and close. (this step is from link above.)

```
FC        = /usr/bin/gfortran # "which gfortran" from terminal gives address
LINKER    = /usr/bin/gfortran
```

run makefile. it should run and show a long list different packages.

```
make -f makefile.g77
```

after it's done it is better to move all generated files to another location from downloads. I moved those to /usr/lib/x64_bin_x13. for me it was easier to do with nautilus while sudo still on. move all *.o and x13as files. close nautilus when you are ready.

```
nautilus
```

open rstudio,install "seasonal"-package and load it

```
install.packages("seasonal")
library(seasonal)
```

tell where those files are

```
Sys.setenv(X13_PATH = "/usr/lib/x64_bin_x13")
```

check if everything is ok

```
> checkX13()
Congratulations! 'seasonal' should work fine!
- the X13_PATH is correctly specified
- the binary executable file has been found
- a test run has been successful
```

logout sudo and close terminal

```
exit
exit
```